# XSRF Cookies not being attached to request header over https iframe loaded over http site

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iframe, csrf

I recently implemented XSRF on MVC/angularjs. The secure site is meant to be loaded in 2 ways, either through a direct post or in an iframe.

here is the code below:-
ANGULAR

```
 .config(function ($httpProvider) {
           $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = '@model.Handlers.XsrfHandler.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME';
           $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = '@model.Handlers.XsrfHandler.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME';
       })
```

MVC - filter

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        //TODO : Check the current value of the cookie if it exists
        if (request.HttpMethod != "GET")
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        //TODO : SHA hash the cookie or something.
        var cookieValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.SessionID;

        if (!request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName))
        {
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(XsrfHandler.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME, cookieValue) { HttpOnly = false };
            response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            response.Cookies[XsrfHandler.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME].Value = cookieValue;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

MVC- handler

```
 protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!xsrfMethods.Contains(request.Method.Method))
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies().SelectMany(chv => chv.Cookies).FirstOrDefault(cs => cs.Name == COOKIE_HEADER_NAME);

        if (cookie == null)
            return CreateError(request);

        var headerValue = request.Headers.GetValues(COOKIE_HEADER_NAME).FirstOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Value) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
            return CreateError(request);

        if (headerValue.Trim().Equals(cookie.Value.Trim(), System.StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        return CreateError(request);
    }
```

Now we have a client who is loading the HTTPS iframe on an HTTP site (dunno why). It still works fine in chrome, firefox but fails in IE. It would seems that the XSRF token is not getting attached to POST request header for IE.

My question is, what are the workaround for the header problem without have to add any edge case logic.

Answer (score 1):

I was just being dumb. the answer was given in several post.
Just needed to add the P3P protocol for IE.

Added P3P to the web.config and voila.

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="P3P" value="CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT&quot;" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```